# Are questions about rhetoric or rhetorical figures on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

The question [Gutes Beispiel für eine Analogie](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/56500/35111) has been closed as off-topic.

**Should questions about rhetoric or rhetorical figures be considered on-topic for this site?**

These questions seem to be rare, but have been considered on-topic in the past. Examples:

- [Abgrenzung von Paradoxon und Oxymoron](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26305/35111)
- [Name einer rhetorischen Figur gesucht](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41088/35111)
- [Rhetorische Figur: Eine Frau geht seinen Weg](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/460/35111)

Since the matter has not been discussed on this site, here are some potentially useful meta discussions from ELU:

- [Does rhetoric fall under EL&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1375/331821)
- [Is the rhetorical perspective out of place in English Language Usage-StackExchange?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3557/331821)

Also have a look at the following ELU tags:

- [rhetoric](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhetoric)
- [rhetorical-devices](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhetorical-devices)

Comment: Die Frage nach der Thetorischen Figur: Eine Frau geht seinen Weg würde ich für on-topic halten, weil es Sprachen gibt, in denen diese Form nicht möglich ist. Es ist nichts typisch deutsches, aber man  benötigt zumindest Kentnisse der Deutschen Sprache um das korrekt zu beantworten.

Comment: Die befragte Frage sehe ich als "unclear what asked" - und da am Schluss nur der Grund angezeigt wird, der die meisten Votes hatte, kann ich nicht erkennen, ob nicht doch wer anders schließen wollte. Jedenfalls sehe ich hier eher das Defizit: statt dem Fragenden mühsam auf die Sprünge zu helfen, damit eine beantwortbare Frage entsteht - ist sie kurzerhand geschlossen - und Neulingen (mind. die unter 101 Punkte) ist kaum klar, _dass_ und wie sie ihre Frage "wiederbeleben" können. (Sehe da Parallelen zu SLAs in Wikipedia)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Unklar finde ich die Frage nicht, aber darum soll es nicht gehen. Ich wollte darauf hinaus, ob Fragen zu rhetorischen Themen on-topic sind.

Comment: Ich fand die Frage ohne weitere Hinweise als nicht sinnvoll beantwortbar. Analogien, die ich für glasklar halte, kann OP für nicht glasklar halten. Mehr Info wäre da wünschenswert gewesen (und wurde angefordert), was mich zum Schluss brachte, die Frage awr eigentlich eine andere. Aber da hat OP nicht mehr drauf reagiert.

Answer (score 6):

I consider them on-topic.

Because a language has it quirks all over. These to understand is (for me) part of the advanced stuff if I want to master a language.

So any question about things like understanding what does it mean or where does that figure come from or when can you answer with this idiom - sounds legit to me.

Answer (score 1):

Es geht ja darum, wie eine Analogie exemplarisch aussieht. Das kann ja von Sprache zu Sprache variieren. Ohne zu wissen, was die Muttersprache des Fragers ist und ob er überhaupt Englisch kann, ist ein Verweis auf die Linguistics oder ELU nicht hilfreich.

Es wäre aber hilfreich, wenn der Frager Beispiele für unklare Analogien nennen würde, und erläuterte, inwiefern diese unklar sind. Jetzt habe ich leider vorschnell für "reopen" gevoted, ich bitte dem Vorbild nicht zu folgen, sondern diese Verbesserung der Frage abzuwarten.

Comment: Die verlinkte Frage ist wirklich nur der Anlaß. Es geht darum, ob Fragen zu Rhetorik im allgemeinen on-topic sein sollen. Die Links zu ELU dienen nur als potentielle Argumentationshilfe, man kann sie auch ignorieren.

Comment: Ja. Allerdings weiß ich nicht, ob man pauschal für alle Fragen zur Rhetorik die gleiche Antwort geben kann. Beispielsweise wenn man fragt, wie im Deutschen ein Strohmannargument aussieht - da wüsste ich jetzt nicht, was daran im Deutschen anders sein sollte als in anderen Sprachen.